# Drop down menu like the default iPad application menus

Tags: xcode, ipad, interface-builder

I'm currently working on my first iOS application to run on the iPad, and I've come across a problem. I have been asked to implement menu's similar to the ones in the default applications such as when you click on the "Calendars" button in the top left of the calendars app.

Only issue is, I cant seem to find a standard UI object that looks like these, with the arrow connecting the menu to the button etc. Is this a standard UI component that I should be able to use, or will I have to imitate them by creating a custom object?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a [`UIPopoverController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html). There isn't an Interface Builder control for this. You need to create one programmatically:

```
UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:someTableViewController];
```

See the documentation for more information and sample projects, specifically [ToolbarSearch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ToolbarSearch/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009461):